# How to use Naïve Bayes Machine Learning to detect and prevent SQL injection attack?

Tags: machine-learning

I mean by question when attacker inject malicious code this code saved in server and algorithm works after that? or what happen in fact ?

Comment: Use prepared statements and avoid this problem altogether.  You'll still get hacked some other way, but at least you can keep out the SQL trolls.

Answer (score 0):

Naive Bayes, or any supervised classification method for that matter, is not a good fit to this problem.

Try with the Gaussian-based outlier detection techniques. This should be a starting point.

Comment: One reason of many: Because your training dataset is biased, meaning you will intuitively have more normal server usage data, while the hacking stuff related data will most likely be quite low. Supervised learning with fail in such a case. 

Have a look into Andrew Ng's ML course in coursera.org to understand the details. Please vote up, if this helps ;)